# AWS Linux Source Code?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, open-source, random-number-generator

We are looking for the source code for Amazon Web Services (AWS) AWS Linux kernel. This should be available under the GPL, but we can't find it, and our requests to Amazon have gone unanswered.

Where can we find it?

We don't want generic Linux kernel sources. We explicitly want the specific code used for the AWS kernel. In particular, we want the code for `/dev/random`.

Answer (score 3):

First hit for me on Google for `aws linux source` :

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/faqs/#source

> Q: Can I view the source code to the Amazon Linux AMI?
>
> Yes. The yumdownloader --source command line tool provided in the
>   Amazon Linux AMI enables viewing of source code inside of Amazon EC2.